# SharePoint Online Classic vs On-Prem (2016/2013)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-on-prem

Can anyone explain the difference between SharePoint Online Classic site and SharePoint on-prem, please?

For example, are those webparts on-prem still available in SharePoint Online classic site?

Any other major difference apart from mention above?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi please see this [blog](http://www.hubfly.com/blog/the-basics/sharepoint-online-vs-sharepoint-onpremises-vs-hybrid/). It provides a very good comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is big and it will take a lot to explain.

1. The key is that Online is hosted somewhere in Microsoft data centers
   you don't take care for the actual machine server only for
   SharePoint. So if you have On-Prem machine you need to buy licence
   like Server, Microsoft Server operation system, SharePoint, SQL and
   so on.
2. SharePoint Online doesn't support code behind you need to create
   provided hosted app that means that SharePoint uses a Azure site or
   IIS local site for the c# code of the app. You can find more on how
   to use them [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)
3. There are many, many other things that you can read [OnPrem vs Online](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-on-premises-vs-sharepoint-online)